# After a process calls syscall wait(), who will wake it up?

Tags: process, scheduling, system-calls

I have a general idea that a process can be in `ready_queue` where CPU selects candidate to run next. And there are these other queues on which a process waits for (broadly speaking) events. I know from OS courses long time ago that there are wait queues for IO and interrupts. My questions are:

1. There are many events a process can wait on. Is there a wait queue corresponding to each such event?
2. Are these wait queues created/destroyed dynamically? If so, which kernel module is responsible for managing these queues? The scheduler? Are there any predefined queues that will always exist?
3. To eventually get a waiting process off a wait queue, does the kernel have a way of mapping from each actual event (either hardware or software) to the wait queue, and then remove **ALL** processes on that queue? If so, what mechanisms does a kernel employ?

To give an example:

```
....
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) { // child process
    // Do something for a second;
}
else { // parent process
    wait(NULL);
    printf("Child completed.");
}
....
```

`wait(NULL)` is a blocking system call. I want to know the rest of the journey the parent process goes through. My take of the story line is as follows, PLEASE correct me if I miss crucial steps or if I am completely wrong:

1. Normal system call setup through libc runtime. Now parent process is in kernel mode, ready to execute whatever is in `wait()` syscall.
2. `wait(NULL)` creates a wait queue where the kernel can later find this queue.
3. `wait(NULL)` puts the parent process onto this queue, creates an entry in some map that says "If I (the kernel) ever receives an software interrupt, signal, or whatever that indicates that the child process is finished, scheduler should come look at this wait queue".
4. Child process finishes and kernel somehow noticed this fact. Kernel context switches to scheduler, which looks up in the map to find the wait queue where the parent process is on.
5. Scheduler moves the parent process to ready queue, does its magic and sometime later the parent process is finally selected to run.
6. Parent process is still in kernel mode, inside `wait(NULL)` syscall. Now the main job of rest of the syscall is to exit kernel mode and eventually return the parent process to user land.
7. The process continues its journey on the next instruction, and may later be waiting on other wait queues until it finishes.

**PS**: I am hoping to know the inner workings of the OS kernel, what stages a process goes through in the kernel and how the kernel interact and manipulate these processes. I do know the semantics and the contract of the wait() Syscall APIs and that is not what I want to know from this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's explore the kernel sources. First of all, it seems all the
various wait routines (wait, waitid, waitpid, wait3, wait4) end up in the
same system call, `wait4`.  These days you can find system calls in the
kernel by looking for the macros `SYSCALL_DEFINE1` and so, where the number
is the number of parameters, which for `wait4` is coincidentally 4.  Using the
google-based freetext search in the Free Electrons [Linux Cross
Reference](https://elixir.bootlin.com/) we eventually find the [definition](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/kernel/exit.c#L1674):

```
1674 SYSCALL_DEFINE4(wait4, pid_t, upid, int __user *, stat_addr,
1675                 int, options, struct rusage __user *, ru)
```

Here the macro seems to split each parameter into its type and name. This
`wait4` routine does some parameter checking, copies them into a `wait_opts`
structure, and calls `do_wait()`, which is a few lines up in the same file:

```
1677         struct wait_opts wo;
1705         ret = do_wait(&wo);

1551 static long do_wait(struct wait_opts *wo)
```

(I'm missing out lines in these excerpts as you can tell by the
non-consecutive line numbers). 
`do_wait()` sets another field of the structure to the name of a function,
`child_wait_callback()` which is a few lines up in the same file. Another
field is set to `current`. This is a major "global" that points to
information held about the current task:

```
1558         init_waitqueue_func_entry(&wo->child_wait, child_wait_callback);
1559         wo->child_wait.private = current;
```

The structure is then added to a queue specifically designed for a process
to wait for SIGCHLD signals, `current->signal->wait_chldexit`:

```
1560         add_wait_queue(&current->signal->wait_chldexit, &wo->child_wait);
```

Let's look at `current`. It is quite hard to find its definition as it
varies per architecture, and following it to find the final structure is a
bit of a rabbit warren. Eg [current.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/include/asm-generic/current.h#L7)

```
  6 #define get_current() (current_thread_info()->task)
  7 #define current get_current()
```

then [thread_info.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h#L163)

```
163 static inline struct thread_info *current_thread_info(void)
165         return (struct thread_info *)(current_top_of_stack() - THREAD_SIZE);

 55 struct thread_info {
 56         struct task_struct      *task;          /* main task structure */
```

So `current` points to a `task_struct`, which we find in [sched.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1459)

```
1460 struct task_struct {
1461         volatile long state;    /* -1 unrunnable, 0 runnable, >0 stopped */
1659 /* signal handlers */
1660         struct signal_struct *signal;
```

So we have found `current->signal` out of `current->signal->wait_chldexit`,
and the struct `signal_struct` is in the same file:

```
670 struct signal_struct {
677         wait_queue_head_t       wait_chldexit;  /* for wait4() */
```

So the `add_wait_queue()` call we had got to above refers to this
`wait_chldexit` structure of type `wait_queue_head_t`.

A wait queue is simply an initially empty, doubly-linked list of structures that contain a
`struct list_head` [types.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/include/linux/types.h#L184)

```
184 struct list_head {
185         struct list_head *next, *prev;
186 };
```

The call `add_wait_queue()`
[wait.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/kernel/sched/wait.c#L23) 
temporarily locks the structure and via an inline function
[wait.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/include/linux/wait.h#L165) 
calls `list_add()` which you can find in
[list.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/include/linux/list.h#L61).
This sets the next and prev pointers appropriately to add the new item on
the list.
An empty list has the two pointers pointing at the list_head structure.

After adding the new entry to the list, the `wait4()` system call sets a
flag that will remove the process from the runnable queue on the next
reschedule and calls `do_wait_thread()`:

```
1573         set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
1577                 retval = do_wait_thread(wo, tsk);
```

This routine calls `wait_consider_task()` for each child of the process:

```
1501 static int do_wait_thread(struct wait_opts *wo, struct task_struct *tsk)
1505         list_for_each_entry(p, &tsk->children, sibling) {
1506                 int ret = wait_consider_task(wo, 0, p);
```

which goes very deep but in fact is just trying to see if any child already
satisfies the syscall, and we can return with the data immediately. The
interesting case for you is when nothing is found, but there are still running
children. We end up calling `schedule()`, which is when the process gives
up the cpu and our system call "hangs" for a future event.

```
1594                 if (!signal_pending(current)) {
1595                         schedule();
1596                         goto repeat;
1597                 }
```

When the process is woken up, it will continue with the code after
`schedule()` and again go through all the children to see if the wait
condition is satisfied, and probably return to the caller.

What wakes up the process to do that? A child dies and generates a SIGCHLD
signal. 
In [signal.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/kernel/signal.c#L1656)
`do_notify_parent()` is called by a process as it dies:

```
1566  * Let a parent know about the death of a child.
1572 bool do_notify_parent(struct task_struct *tsk, int sig)
1656         __wake_up_parent(tsk, tsk->parent);
```

`__wake_up_parent()` calls `__wake_up_sync_key()` *and uses exactly the
`wait_chldexit` wait queue we set up previously.*
[exit.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/kernel/exit.c#L1545)

```
1545 void __wake_up_parent(struct task_struct *p, struct task_struct *parent)
1547         __wake_up_sync_key(&parent->signal->wait_chldexit,
1548                                 TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE, 1, p);
```

I think we should stop there, as `wait()` is clearly one of the more
complex examples of a system call and the use of wait queues. You can find
a simpler presentation of the mechanism in this 3 page [Linux Journal
article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8144) from 2005. Many things
have changed, but the principle is explained. You might also buy the books 
"Linux Device Drivers" and "Linux Kernel Development", or check out the
earlier editions of these that can be found online.

For the "Anatomy Of A System Call" on the way from user space to the kernel
you might read these [lwn](https://lwn.net/Articles/604287/) [articles](https://lwn.net/Articles/604515/).

---

Wait queues are heavily used throughout the kernel whenever a task,
needs to wait for some condition. A grep through the kernel sources finds
over 1200 calls of `init_waitqueue_head()` which is how you initialise a
waitqueue you have dynamically created by simply `kmalloc()`-ing the space
to hold the structure.

A grep for the `DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD()` macro finds over 150 uses of
this declaration of a static waitqueue structure. There is no intrinsic
difference between these. A driver, for example, can choose either method
to create a wait queue, often depending on whether it can manage
many similar devices, each with their own queue, or is only expecting one device.

No central code is responsible for these queues, though there is common
code to simplify their use. A driver, for example, might create an empty
wait queue when it is installed and initialised. When you use it to read data from some
hardware, it might start the read operation by writing directly into the
registers of the hardware, then queue an entry (for "this" task, i.e. `current`) on its wait queue to give up
the cpu until the hardware has the data ready.

The hardware would then interrupt the cpu, and the kernel would call the
driver's interrupt handler (registered at initialisation). The handler code
would simply call `wake_up()` on the wait queue, for the kernel to
put all tasks on the wait queue back in the run queue.

When the task gets the cpu again, it continues where it left off (in
`schedule()`) and checks that the hardware has completed the operation, and
can then return the data to the user.

So the kernel is not responsible for the driver's wait queue, as it only
looks at it when the driver calls it to do so. There is no mapping from the
hardware interrupt to the wait queue, for example.

If there are several tasks on the same wait queue, there are variants of
the `wake_up()` call that can be used to wake up only 1 task, or all of
them, or only those that are in an interruptable wait (i.e. are designed to
be able to cancel the operation and return to the user in case of a
signal), and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the deep code dive! Can you also, on a higher level, address my initial 3 questions? After reading your answer, it feels like the scheduler has pre-constructed all sorts of wait queues, for all the possible types of events that a process can wait on. Is that correct?

Comment: I added some explanation at the end after a horizontal line.

Answer (score 0):

In order to wait for a child process to terminate, a parent process will just execute a wait() system call. This call will suspend the parent process until any of its child processes terminates, at which time the wait() call returns and the parent process can continue.

The prototype for the wait( call is:

```
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h>

pid_t wait(int *status);
```

The return value from wait is the PID of the child process which terminated. The parameter to wait() is a pointer to a location which will receive the child's exit status value when it terminates.

When a process terminates it executes an exit() system call, either directly in its own code, or indirectly via library code. The prototype for the exit() call is:

```
#include <std1ib.h>

void exit(int status);
```

The exit() call has no return value as the process that calls it terminates and so couldn't receive a value anyway. Notice, however, that exit() does take a parameter value - status. As well as causing a waiting parent process to resume execution, exit() also returns the status parameter value to the parent process via the location pointed to by the wait() parameter.

In fact, wait() can return several different pieces of information via the value to which the status parameter points. Consequently, a macro is provided called WEXITSTATUS() (accessed via ) which can extract and return the child's exit status. The following code fragment shows its use:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>

int statval, exstat; 
pid_t pid;

pid = wait(&statval);
exstat = WEXITSTATUS(statval);
```

In fact, the version of wait() that we have just seen is only the simplest version available under Linux. The new POSIX version is called waitpid. The prototype for waitpid() is:

```
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h>

pid_t waitpid(pid_t pid, int *status, int options);
```

where pid specifies what to wait for, status is the same as the simple wait() parameter and options allows you to specify that a call to waitpid() should not suspend the parent process if no child process is ready to report its exit status.

The various possibilities for the pid parameter are:

```
< -1 wait for a child whose PGID is -pid
-1   same behavior as standard wait()
0    wait for child whose PGID = PGID of calling process
> 0  wait for a child whose PID = pid
```

The standard wait() call is now redundant as the following waitpid() call is exactly equivalent:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>

int statval; 
pid_t pid;

pid = waitpid(-1, &statval, 0);
```

It is possible for a child process which only executes for a very short time to terminate before its parent process has had the chance to wait() for it. In these circumstances the child process will enter a state, known as a zombie state, in which all its resources have been released back to the system except for its process data structure, which holds its exit status. When the parent eventually wait()s for the child, the exit status is delivered immediately and then the process data structure can also be released back to the system.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed explanation on the semantics of these syscalls. But it is not at all what the question asked for. I want to know how the OS internal works. Especially how the wait queues work. For example, how does the parent get notified when its child is terminated.

Comment: i don't know about any wait queues its pointers. the parent get not when the exit is called in a child but if it wasn't caught then it will be something called zombie (just like my nickname here)

Comment: Don't you feel there is a gap when you say "the parent got notified when exit is called in a child process"? That is what I want to know, ie, how the kernel finds the parent and go wake it up from some wait queues, if any.